# Convergence of integral implies integrand is asymptotically bounded above by a power law that has a convergent integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a continuous, real-valued function on $[1,\infty)$ such that
$\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ is finite.

Does this necessarily imply that there exists $\kappa > 0$ such that $f(x) = O\!\left( \frac{1}{x^{1+\kappa}} \right)$ ?

That is ([expanding the big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)), there exists $\kappa > 0$, $M > 0$, $x_0 > a$ such that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{M}{x^{1+\kappa}}$ for all $x \geq x_0$?

*Remark*: When $\kappa > 0$ we have $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{1+\kappa}} \, dx = \left[ \frac{-1}{\kappa x^{\kappa}}\right]_{1}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{\kappa}$ which is finite.

*Why I am asking*: I have a situation where I have a convergent integral, and want to use feature of the integrand to establish whether another integral is convergent.  Many thanks in advance.

*Edit*: See this [question & answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4071584/190548) for a revised question that got to an answer that I applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

**Example**: Let $f$ be mostly zero, except centered at every half-integer $n+\frac12$, $n\geq 1$, we have a triangle function of height $1$ and base $1/n^2$.  In other words,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\max(0,1-2n^2\lvert n+\tfrac12-x\rvert)
$$
Then $\sup_{x\geq N}f(x)=1$ for all $N$ so it doesn't decay.  But the total area of triangles, $\frac12\zeta(2)$, is finite.

In fact, you can tweak this example so that $\sup_{x\geq N}f(x)=\infty$, and if you know about bump functions, get $f$ infinitely differentiable too.